# How to correctly create a sequence diagram?

Tags: java, uml, class-diagram, sequence-diagram

I have some doubts about this Sequence Diagram, I haven't found similar examples on the web so I can't compare my solution.

The exercise requires modeling the invocation of the `listAllFiles` method of the `Directory` class with a sequence diagram.

This is the Java code:

```
public class Directory { 
         public List<File> listAllFiles(String path) { 
                List<File> all = newArrayList<File>(); 
                File[] list = new File(path).listFiles(); 
                if(list != null) { 
                   for (File f:list) { 
                       if(f.isDirectory()) { 
                       
                           all.addAll(listAllFiles(f.getAbsolutePath())); 
                           
                       } else { 
                       
                            all.add(f.getAbsoluteFile()); 
                       }
                   } 
                } 
                  return all; 
           } 
}
```

This is my sequence diagram:

[image]

I modified my solution following the advice in the replies:

[image]

Comment: @aled Hi I have some doubts about my sequence diagram solution, I wanted to know if it was represented correctly or what I can improve. Thank you

Comment: This is not the right site for asking to review code or diagrams. This is a Q&A site for specific questions. See the Help Center page to understand what is on topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @LucaCardone yes, this is the way. Don't heistate to put the original messag ename after «create». The f:File should be in the loop (since it's repetitive). While there is an ambiguity, I'd prefer a create message from list to f head, to suggest it's an iterator on the list. But the way you showed it is not wrong either since the for creates the f. I'd also add a X crossing lifeline of f at the end of the loop.

Comment: @Christophe Thanks! Regarding the X, do you mean that I should add it within the loop? What do you mean by original message ename after <<create>>? Thanks again for your time

Comment: @LucaCardone I meant the constructor used after the <<create>>.  The cross that ends the lifeline of f would indeed be at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Recommendation

The first recommendation for making a useful sequence diagram, is to chose the **right level of abstraction**. Indeed, the diagram's value is to show in a simple way some complex interactions that are difficult to grasp when just reading the code.

Unfortunately, here it is just the contrary: we instantly understand the code when reading it. All this is mainly about one classe's method, using standard library elements such as `File` or `List`.  But showing it as a sequence diagram makes it look really complicated.  Moreover, imagine the challenge when maintaining the code:  your diagram will very quickly be out of sync, becoming useless.

In short: **don't use UML for graphic programming**.  It's not forbidden by the UML specs, but it's really not worth the effort.

### For the sake of the exercise, despite the recommendation above

#### Fundamental improvements

The lifelines shall correspond to objects and not to classes.  Keeping it at class level, makes it difficult to distinguish the array of `File` and the individual `File`s you're looping on.  Try with the following lifelines:  `:Directory` (i.e. anonymous object of class `Directory`), `all:List<File>`, `list:File[]`, `f:File`.

You could also use `File` and `ArrayList<File>` if you want to show the use of static operations that are object independent, but it would make the diagram more complex than needed for the creation of the objects.  Instead, I'd advise to show graphically the [create message](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/interaction-message.html#create) for each local object, directly from the creator to the head of the lifeline, allocating the object visually to the right scope.  To avoid ambiguity, you should also show the [delete message](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/interaction-message.html#delete) (or at least the X), especially for objects that have a limited scope, like `f`.

The create message with a lifeline head that starts from the message, you'll make in particular clear that some objects only exist for the time of an iteration. This will dramatically improve the understanding of your intent. As it is, we just don't get it, if we wouldn't see the code.

#### Minor improvements

In the `alt` guard, put just the condition or `else`, but never the `if`.

You may well show the parameters of the message,  and the name of the returned result, but it's not mandatory, and would not significantly improve understandability here.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I applied what you told me, hopefully in the right way. I have edited the post with a new solution, I am open to other advice

Comment: it's `operation`, not `method` ;-)

Comment: @qwerty_so in UML, yes. But the only place where I use "method" is when I refer to the java code that is being modeled. I use therefore the implementation language terminology .  Btw,  in the same sentence I also refer to the "standard library" which is also relevant for the implementation language and not to UML ;-)